# How do I compute the power consumption of a DRAM refresh?

Tags: computer-architecture, digital-circuits

Given a DRAM-based memory system with a total capacity of $x$ bytes, $y$ DRAM rows and a refresh time of $t$ milliseconds, how do I compute the power consumption for one DRAM refresh? I couldn't find something concerning this question so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P = I \cdot \Delta V$, meaning one has to find the current consumption $I$ and the difference in voltage $\Delta V$, often denoted by $V_{dd}$ of the respective DRAM, in this case one can choose an arbitrary DRAM since nothing is specified.